# RecyclerView ItemAnimator change order of moving items in default animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that load a list of cards each one with a favorite button. When user touch that button I change the order of my list items setting to first position the new favorite card. That change displays the default animation when NotifyItemMoved is called but I want to display in front the item that is moving up. The default animation displays the item that is moving to botton in front of the rest of the items.

Searching a bit I found that I can implement a custom ItemAnimator and use something like this:

```
override fun animateMove(
        holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
        fromX: Int,
        fromY: Int,
        toX: Int,
        toY: Int
    ): Boolean {
        if ( fromY > toY) {
            holder?.itemView?.bringToFront()
        }

        return super.animateMove(holder, fromX, fromY, toX, toY)
    }
```

It looks that works well but when I scroll the list it crashes with this error:  `java.lang.RuntimeException: trying to unhide a view that was not hiddenandroidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`
If I remove `holder?.itemView?.bringToFront()` the default animation runs well again without any crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update to my question]

The only thing that worked for me was doing something like this and set it to the RecyclerView:

```
class RecyclerViewItemAnimator : DefaultItemAnimator() {
    override fun animateMove(
        holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
        fromX: Int,
        fromY: Int,
        toX: Int,
        toY: Int
    ): Boolean {
        val result = super.animateMove(holder, fromX, fromY, toX, toY)
        if (holder?.itemView != null && fromY > toY) {
            holder.itemView.translationZ = 1f // increase the elevation
        }
        return result
    }

    override fun onAnimationFinished(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        viewHolder.itemView.translationZ = 0f // reset the elevation
        super.onAnimationFinished(viewHolder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the "trying to unhide a view that was not hidden" error is because the bringToFront() method of View can interfere with the RecyclerView's internal view recycling mechanism. When a view is recycled, it is hidden and re-used for another item in the list. By calling bringToFront() on a view, you are potentially interfering with this process and causing the view to be incorrectly re-used for a different item.

One way to avoid this issue is to create a custom RecyclerView.ItemAnimator that overrides the animateChange() method to bring the moved view to the front, but does not interfere with the view recycling process. Here's an example implementation:

```
class CustomItemAnimator : DefaultItemAnimator() {

    override fun animateChange(
        oldHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
        newHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
        preInfo: ItemHolderInfo?,
        postInfo: ItemHolderInfo?
    ): Boolean {
        if (oldHolder != null && newHolder != null) {
            // Check if the item is being moved up (i.e. to a lower index)
            if (oldHolder.adapterPosition > newHolder.adapterPosition) {
                // Bring the new holder's item view to the front
                newHolder.itemView.bringToFront()
            }
        }

        return super.animateChange(oldHolder, newHolder, preInfo, postInfo)
    }
}
```

This implementation only brings the new holder's item view to the front when the item is being moved up (i.e., to a lower index). This should allow the default RecyclerView view recycling mechanism to work correctly.

To use this custom ItemAnimator, set it on your RecyclerView using the setItemAnimator() method:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(CustomItemAnimator())
```

Note: This implementation assumes that each item in the RecyclerView is represented by a single view in the ViewHolder. If you have complex item layouts with multiple views, you may need to modify this implementation to ensure that only the item view is brought to the front.